# Invoking second view from button click in view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, castle-windsor

Trying to work through Castle Windsor with WPF and MVVM design pattern. I have three projects in my solution i.e. MainView, ViewModel and IoCInstaller Project.

MainView is dependent upon IoCInstaller and ViewModel.
IoCInstaller is dependent upon ViewModel.

Now I want to invoke a SecondView from a button click action in ViewModel but based on dependencies, I am finding it hard. I know that my castle windsor implementation is not ideal but I am not finding any good answer on the ideal way of its implementation. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

After reading documentation and searching through web I made basic castle implementation work but when it comes to WPF and MVVM I am stuck.

***ViewModel Project***

```cs
public partial class MainView : Window
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var iocContainer = IoCInstaller.WindsorContainer;
        iocContainer.Install(new IoCInstaller());

        var mainWindowViewModel = iocContainer.Resolve<IMainWindowViewModel>();
        mainWindowViewModel.Initialize(iocContainer);
        DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    }
}
```

***IoCInstaller Project***

```cs
public class IoCInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    private static WindsorContainer _windsorContainer;
    public static WindsorContainer WindsorContainer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_windsorContainer == null)
            {
                _windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
                return _windsorContainer;
            }
            else
            {
                return _windsorContainer;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For<IViewModel>());
    }
}
```

and finally ***ViewModel project***

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel 
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void Initialize(WindsorContainer windsorContainer)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Initializing main view model ");
        iocContainer = windsorContainer;
    }

    public void MyActionForBttnClicked()
    {
        //invoke second view
    }

    //Other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're currently using `Castle.Windsor` is more like a ServiceLocator than an IOC Container.
I would suggest that you use [typed factories](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) to resolve your classes. With factories you don't need a `public static WindsorContainer` because you only call `Resolve` once (also see the [Three-Calls-Pattern](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/three-calls-pattern.md)).

Start by using a `Bootstrapper`-Class where you call your `IWindsorInstaller`s and register the use of `TypedFactoryFacility`:

```cs
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public IWindsorContainer BootstrapContainer()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        return container.Install(new IocInstaller());
    }
}
```

You can call the `BootstrapContainer()` either from your `MainView` or from your `App.xaml.cs`.

Now create a factory for your `ViewModel`:

```cs
public interface IViewModelFactory
{
    IViewModel Create();

    void Release(IViewModel viewModel);
}
```

You don't need to implement this factory, Windsor does this for you.
The only thing you need to do is to change your `IocInstaller` and register your `IViewModelFactory`:

```cs
public class IocInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IViewModel>().ImplementedBy<MainWindowViewModel>().LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(Component.For<IViewModelFactory>().AsFactory());
    }
}
```

Make sure you are familiar with the available `Lifestyles`. The default is `LifestyleSingleton()` while you probably want to use `LifestyleTransient()`. For more information see [this link](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md).

To create your `ViewModel` you can then call `Resolve` at the location where you called your `Bootstrapper` and get the `IViewModelFactory`:

```cs
public MainView()
{
    //other stuff

    Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
    IWindsorContainer container = bootstrapper.BootstrapContainer();

    IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory = container.Resolve<IViewModelFactory>();
    IViewModel viewModel = viewModelFactory.Create();

    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

If you want to open another window from your `ViewModel` now, you can do this pretty easy.
First create a factory for your second view model:

```cs
public interface ISecondViewModelFactory
{
    ISecondViewModel Create();

    void Release(ISecondViewModel secondViewModel);
}
```

Then register the new classes in your `IocInstaller`:

```cs
public class IocInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        //registration for ViewModel

        container.Register(Component.For<ISecondViewModel>().ImplementedBy<SecondViewModel>().LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(Component.For<ISecondViewModelFactory>().AsFactory());
    }
}
```

The new `ISecondViewModelFactory` can now be set as a parameter of the constructor of your `ViewModel`:

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IViewModel 
{
    private readonly ISecondViewModelFactory _secondViewModelFactory;

    public ViewModel(ISecondViewModelFactory secondViewModelFactory)
    {
        _secondViewModelFactory = secondViewModelFactory;
    }
}
```

The `ISecondViewModelFactory` gets resolved by the Windsor for you so you don't have to care about it.
You can then easily create a new `SecondViewModel` and show a new window with the `SecondViewModel` as your `DataContext`:

```cs
public void MyActionForBttnClicked()
{
    //invoke second view
    ISecondViewModel secondViewModel = _secondViewModelFactory.Create();
    SecondWindow secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
    secondWindow.DataContext = secondViewModel;
    secondWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is this SecondWindow() and where it is defined? if it is a view which is defined in MainView project then again We are in same situation that can not reference MainView project directly from ViewModel Project because of circular reference.

Comment: By saying view I meant Window (WPF) i.e. SecondWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: @Karan: I don't know your project structure, but usually your `ViewModels` are in the same project as your `Views`, because they usually need to reference each other.

Comment: However if this is just not an option, you could create a `SecondWindowFactory` and create your `SecondWindow` with `Castle.Windsor` as well.